# Input with innerHTML Angular 2

Tags: html, css, angular

Hi i am using Angular 2+ Typescript, I want to display input of text with css and html similar to innerHTML.
I've tried to do something like this:

```
<input [innerHTML] formControlName="descriptionCtrl" matInput></input>
```

What is the method to display css and html in input?

edit:
I was looking for a rich text editor.

Answer (score 0):

**innerHTML** normally used for div, span, td and similar elements.

at your case you can add **value** or **placeholder** to display text inside your input

Comment: I tried but it does not work, placeholer is not suitable because the input changes and value didn't work

Comment: can you be more specific what are you trying to do?,
you can writ in Hebrew.